# find which samples are in an integer pool

Tags: python, numpy

I have two arrays of integers, one very large `pool` (can have hundreds of thousands of entries) and one `samples` (can also have many, but only in the order of hundreds/thousands). For each entry in `samples`, I need to find out if it is in `pool`. I can do an explicit loop:

```py
import numpy as np


rng = np.random.default_rng(0)

n = 1000
m = 10
pool = rng.integers(0, 100000, n)
samples = rng.integers(0, 100000, m)

is_in_pool = [s in pool for s in samples]
```

There certainly is a faster variant though.

Any hints?

Comment: Not sure if it is faster, but the `numpy` way to do it, is to use `isin` https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html like so:
`np.isin(samples, pool)`

Comment: @AlexG If you promote your reply to an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

The `numpy` way to do it, is to use [isin](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html):

```
np.isin(samples, pool)

# Output
array([False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False, False])
```

However this is not faster than the list comprehension, which is optimized in C, too. A little speedup can be gained if both arrays are unique using `assume_unique=True` in `np.isin`.
The fastest I could get is to convert the pool into a `set` which as a hash map has constant lookup time. The conversion to a `set` takes some time and is not included in the following performance measurement of the different approaches which makes the approach using a `set` not a fair comparison.

```
pool_set = set(pool)

%%timeit
[s in pool_set for s in samples]
1.81 µs ± 8.17 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)


%%timeit
[s in pool for s in samples]
44.5 µs ± 3.28 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)


%%timeit
np.isin(samples, pool, assume_unique=True)
57.7 µs ± 922 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)


%%timeit
np.isin(samples, pool)
87.9 µs ± 3.09 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

As a hint, you can speed this calculation up by removing duplicates from the arrays.

Hint 2: There is a `numpy` function that can answer this for you.